# Getting result out of a function into a usable variable?

Tags: javascript, html

So I have a simple HTML file that I want to have a select option drop down menu. I have made that when a selection is made the page reloads retaining the option but I can't get the result outside of the function.

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
</head><body>
  <select id="mySelect" onchange = "getSelectValue();">
    <optgroup label="Working">
        <option value="rage.zip">Streets of Rage</option>
        <option value="quest.zip">Money Quest</option>
    </optgroup>
</select>

<div style="width:640px;height:480px;max-width:100%">
<script type="text/javascript">
window.addEventListener('load', function(){
    if (localStorage.pick) {
        var sel = document.querySelector('#mySelect');
        sel.value = localStorage.pick;
    }
});

function getSelectValue(){
    var sel = document.querySelector('#mySelect');
    localStorage.pick = sel.value;
    location.reload();
    return sel.value;
}

    EJS_player = '#game';
    EJS_gameUrl = ; // Url to Game rom
    EJS_gameID = 4; // ID in your website, required for netplay.
    EJS_core = 'segaMD';
</script>
<script src="https://www.emulatorjs.com/loader.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

My issue is the select option result is in the **sel.value**. I need that value to `EJS_gameUrl = .`

So if the option 1 is select which is rage.zip then it should be filled in the `EJS_gameUrl = "rage.zip"`

Im just having trouble with getting that result out of the function . I would prefer to define it to a variable and just add the variable in the `EJS_gameUrl = x;` or similar. How can I go about this?

Comment: i believe i need to define the listener before the addEventListener. But Im unsure on how to proceed.

Answer (score 1):

See [Storing the information you need — Variables](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/First_steps/Variables), [`Storage.setItem`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Storage/setItem) and [`Storage.getItem`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Storage/getItem).

Your code should be something along the lines of:

```js
const EJS_player = '#game';
let EJS_gameUrl = ''; // Url to Game rom
const EJS_gameID = 4; // ID in your website, required for netplay.
const EJS_core = 'segaMD';

window.addEventListener('load', function() {
  const storedValue = localStorage.getItem('mySelect');
  if (storedValue) {
    var sel = document.querySelector('#mySelect');
    sel.value = storedValue;
    EJS_gameUrl = storedValue;
  }
});

function getSelectValue() {
  localStorage.setItem('mySelect', this.value);
  location.reload();
}

console.log(EJS_gameUrl)
```

```html
<select id="mySelect" onchange="getSelectValue();">
  <optgroup label="Working">
    <option value="rage.zip">Streets of Rage</option>
    <option value="quest.zip">Money Quest</option>
  </optgroup>
</select>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I'll need to read up on the variables. As going by your example doesn't seem to store it in the EJS_gameUrl. Will try to figure out what the console.log actually pulls if I try to alert(); on it it just gives me this "function log() { [native code] }"